# Block labels from another layer to cover points

Tags: qgis, labeling, point

I have these road map labels generated from a table and they are overlapping with my points from another table or layer. How do I stop that from happening? I want to see the points clearly. If I adjust the label to be above the road lines, other points get covered.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

To avoid labels being placed over objects from antother layer, use a label placement defined by Geometry generator and define a geometry that excludes the area around these objects (a buffer).

Use this expression to **exclude** an area of 2000 map units around the points from the layer `point` for the postion of the labels:

```
difference (
    buffer($geometry,150),
    buffer (
        aggregate( 
            'point', 
            'collect', 
            $geometry
        ), 
        2000
    )
)
```

*The expression in action: the blue area is the area where label placement is allowed (the white section of the road represents the buffer aorund the red dot):*
[image]

Comment: That could be really helpful, Thank you for your time and effort but I'm not sure I have the geometry generator option here. I am a beginner and I am using this software for the first time.

Comment: You should really look at the picture that Babel gave… Geometry generator is not an option! Just tick it, and copy past the code above!

Comment: Indeed: have a closer look, the Geometry generator option must be there. Show us your label setting options/placement tab if you  can't find it.

Answer (score 3):

In the labeling properties of the point layer, choose `Blocking` and set an obstacle weight.

[image]

Comment: Hi, my point layer does not have labels. The labels seen here is on my road layer. Also I am using version 2.18.

Comment: Yes, I understood that the labels are from your roads and the answer above should solve your problem, because you choose to block other labels from covering your points. It should be available in QGIS 2.18.

Comment: Is it this? https://imgur.com/a/Wcm75s2

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/TEYtMQ4 I tried it but according to my layer I now get numbers since its  count points and I don't think I want that

Comment: No, that's not the way. Isn't there an option in that drop-down menu where you have selected `Show labels for this layer` that says `Blocking`?

Comment: @Babel It does work with labels from other layers.

Comment: @CezarB yes, you're right, I tried it. Sorry for inconvenience :-)